# formatting individual strings in excel

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, conditional-formatting, openoffice-calc

I'd like to learn how to use conditional formatting in Excel or, preferably, OpenOffice Calc to format a string every time it appears.

E.g., I have a table of medical structures. I want to automate italicizing and coloring the words "Superior, Inferior, Anterior, Posterior, Medial, and Lateral" as soon as the cell is finished for increased visibility and ease of reading.

So far, I only know how to change the formatting of the entire cell based on its contents, but not the specific string.

Any help would be wonderful, thanks.

Comment: Are you asking for a recommendation to a tutorial? Or are you asking for a concrete example? The former is generally frowned upon here on StackOverflow. For the later you need to be fairly specific.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I'm looking for a concrete example or at least an explanation so I can do it myself. My response to Del Kirksey below might make things more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional formatting with a formula. Navigate to `Conditional Formatting` > `New Rule` > `Use a formula to determine which cells to format`. And then enter the formula `=SEARCH("Anterior",A1,1)` in the formula box. Then set the Format you'd like, using the Format button. Then click OK.

In the next window, click in the box that allows you to select which cells to apply the formatting to. Repeat this step for each word, Superior, Inferior, Anterior, Medial, etc..

A few screenshots below to clarify.

[image: Excel condtitional formatting]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response! Unfortunately, it's not quite what I was looking for. Let me clarify.

I'd like to do something like [this](http://imgur.com/a/9xSN3)

There's other formatted text in the target cell, but I'd only like to format a particular string (let me know if I'm using that term incorrectly) when it appears _within_ the cell without changing the surrounding text.

Comment: Ah, got it now! Though I'm not sure that this is possible using conditional formatting. The only way I can think of doing this would be to use VBA. Do you have experience with VBA?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I can sort of tell what's going on when I read it, but I can't write it from scratch faster than I can use the find and replace tool. This definitely would have been handy to automate though.

Thanks for your help so far!